# Spring Security not routing to custom login page 404 error

Tags: java, angularjs, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to implement a custom login page for Spring Security for an Angular web app, but cannot for the life of me get it to properly redirect to my custom login page. I have the following Spring Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

This is my routing logic in the controller:

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : '/admin/listing.html',
        controller : 'ListingCtrl'
    }).when('/create', {
        templateUrl : '/admin/create.html',
        controller : 'CreateCtrl'
    }).when('/edit/:id', {
        templateUrl : '/admin/edit.html',
        controller : 'EditCtrl'
    }).when('/details/:id', {
        templateUrl : '/admin/details.html',
        controller : 'DetailCtrl'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : '/login.html',
        controller : 'LoginCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
}]);
```

And my folder structure:

```
- public
  |- admin
     |- create.html
     |- details.html
     |- edit.html
     |- listing.html
  app.js
  index.html
  login.html
```

Currently when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/` it does seem to route to `http://localhost:8080/login` but once there it gives me a 404 error. I've tried a few other `http` configurations in the `SecurityConfig` but haven't gotten anything that properly routes me to my login page, which would ideally happen when any resource in the `admin` folder is accessed.

Comment: So if you request http://localhost:8080/login (by typing it in your browser) does it render? How are you mapping to the login.html page within your server side? Did you look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/guides/html5/form.html

Comment: It does not render, I just get the same 404 error. I am not sure what you mean by mapping login.html on the server side, prior to trying Spring Security the Angular route mappings were sufficient for getting the expected page navigation and rendering. I have been referencing that Spring guide but it's possible I did not implement something essential in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an unauthenticated request, you need something on the server side to respond to the URL /login. For example, your server side framework should render login.html.

Angular is client side, so changing your routes will have no impact. The easiest way to do this is to use the following:

```
http
    .formLogin()
        // NOTE removed .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

The configuration above will tell Spring Security to render the log in page.

Without knowing what other frameworks you are using (i.e. are you using Spring MVC?), it is impossible to answer how to have your server side framework render login.html.  If you are using Spring MVC, you can use the [guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/guides/html5/form.html) I mentioned in the comments.

A stab in the dark (since you haven't yet provided your server side technology), is you can change your configuration to be:

```
http
    .formLogin()
        // NOTE: added .html suffix
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

The above configuration will expect a POST to /login.html with the parameters username and password to validate the user.

Comment: I have a controller tagged with Spring's @RestController but that is only to handle my CRUD operations with the database. Are you saying I should be handling my page rendering with that as well somehow? I don't know a lot about this stuff so I have to plead some ignorance

Comment: Adding the html suffix was enough to get it to route to my login page. I assumed since I had in my Angular routing for `/login` to go to `/login.html` that it would get there and I'm not sure I understand why that doesn't work. But, going straight to the HTML works. Thanks!